# NodeJS ejs module fail to install on ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, ejs

I have an application I wrote on nodejs. It works fine on my local machine. Then I decided to test it on a live server. I moved the application to an AWS EC2 instance. When I run "npm install", ejs module always fail to install.

Here is the error
[image]

Comment: What version of node is running on your instance

Comment: Tried 7, tried 12 and tried 13. All result in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could install it with this version of  `ejs`

```
npm i ejs@2.7.1
```

i hope it works for you